# How can i solve error unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
lambTest2 : Int.(Int) -> Int = { i: Int -> i * 2 }
val intTest = 25
val Test = intTest.lambTest2(25)

print(Test)
```

Error:

```
error: unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) 
lambTest2 : Int.(Int) -> Int = { i: Int -> i * 2
```

Comment: Please check Kotlin guide to see how to insert lamda definitions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing declaration?

`val lambTest2 : Int.(Int) -> Int = { i: Int -> i * 2 }`

Add val to your expression